# Change Date Format from millisecond

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have millisecond and i want to convert it in format Feb-01-2014 09:12:12. I have used following code

```
var today = new Date(1419359400000);
var p=today.toLocaleFormat('%b-%d-%Y  %H:%M:%S');
```

But it is not working in chrome

Thanks

Comment: Converting date formats in JS is a nightmare. My advice; use [DateJS](http://datejs.com)

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleFormat reads:

> **Non-standard**
>
> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Use some date library if you find yourself needing to formats a lot or use the native functions `today.getYear()`, `today.getMonth()` etc.

Keep in mind that `toLocaleFormat` uses the *operating system* locale which might not actually be what you want. Your dates might appear in a different language than the rest of your application.